# How to open the previous instance of an Activity and recreate it

Tags: android, android-intent

If I call an activity `Activity_B` and 1 of it's instances is already present in the backstack, I want to go back to that Instance, removing all the activities in between, and recreate that instance(to refresh content).

**I tried:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and in **Activity_B:**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d("Activity_B", "onNewIntent");
    //Thought of refreshing the content here.
}
```

I never found anything which will do all the above actions.

The best I could found was `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` which will not recreate the Activty, instead it will call `onNewIntent()` where I can refresh the content.

But every time a new instance of the **Activity_B** is called.

What am I missing?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) instead. It will bring the previously running instance of your activity to the front if it exists.

Once the activity comes to the foreground, it's `onResume()` method will be called as usual where you can refresh your UI.